# How can I use a boolean modifier on 2 objects at once?

Tags: modifiers

I'm making dies for extruders used for pottery work, so I'm cutting shapes into multiple dies at a time. For now, I only have two dies to modify at a time. Here's the two dies with a prism going through them:
[image]
I have two cylinders here, with a shape going through them. I know I can select one at a time, add a boolean modifier, then apply it and I'll have a hole in the shape of the tall prism cut through the selected cylinder. Then I have to repeat for the 2nd cylinder.

I've tried selecting both cylinders and adding a boolean modifier and doing both in one shot, but it doesn't work. For now, it's trivial, but as I add more dies to work with, it'll be more and more frustrating to repeat the process multiple times.

Is there a way to use the boolean modifier on two or more objects at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select all the objects you want to bool then hit <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> to join them into one object.
Apply your bool modifier.
In Edit mode, select <kbd>A</kbd>ll then <kbd>P</kbd> Separate > <kbd>By Loose Parts</kbd>.
You'll now have all your original objects with the modifier applied.

Answer (score 2):

### You can link modifiers to other objects.

Add the modifier to 1 object.

Select the other objects and then the one with the modifier.

Press <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to open the Link menu. Choose Modifiers.

Now the rest of your objects should share modifiers of the first.

(However, you'll still have to Apply the modifiers separately on each object.)

Alteratively (this may be better), you can enable the Copy Attributes add-on to copy the modifiers.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/interface/copy_attributes.html

Comment: I tried this. I saw the outlines that show the modifier and the effect it had on both objects, but then when I picked "Apply," it only applied it to the first cylinder.

Comment: Could you join all your cylinders into a single object with CTRL-J, apply the modifier to the single object, and then in Edit mode select All then separate it into individual objects again using P > Separate by Loose Parts?

Comment: Just tried this after sorting the problem in your other question (https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/268131/why-doesnt-a-boolean-modifier-work-with-this-prism) and it works fine.

Comment: @JohnEason Yes that works fine. (If I do this as much as I suspect, I'm going to have to just write a Python program so when I make a prism, I can run it as a macro and it'll do it all for me at that poiny.