# Why doesn't a boolean modifier work with this prism?

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves

I am taking a Bezier curve, turning it into a mesh, then mirroring it on the X axis and joining the two meshes, then I mirror it on the Y axis and join them. I merge the vertices where the joints were made, then create a face and make a prism out of it. Then I duplicate it (part of my process to be sure I keep the original one) and move it so it goes through a cylinder and try to apply a boolean modifier (using the Difference option). But the boolean modifier does nothing.

Here's a screenshot of what I'm working with:
[image]

The lower left item is the bezier curve I'm working with. (The original. I created a duplicate to work with.) I turn it into a mesh. From there, I have tried duplicating and mirroring with CTRL-M and I have also used the Mirror modifier. (In both cases, of course, I have to use the 3D cursor to change the object's origin so I can do the mirroring properly.) I have tried this mirroring the X axis first and the Y axis first.

I have also varied creating the face or faces. I have created a face once I have one mesh going all the way around, then extruded. I have also extruded, then created both the top and bottom face separately.

No matter what I do to take this Bezier, convert it to a mesh, create the shape I need by mirroring it twice, extruding it, and adding a top and bottom face, once I move it into place and try to modify the cylinder with it so I have a hole in the cylinder that matches the prism shape, it will not work. Nothing happens and the cylinder is not modified at all.

What am I doing wrong and why won't this prism work as an object for the modifier?

Blend file: [image]

(Note - adding the .blend file once I have the URL for this question for Blend-Exchange. If there's a way to do that before posting the question and editing later, I'm open to it.)

Comment: Sometimes the Exact solver doesn't work.  Try switching to the Fast Solver.  It works on your object in 3.2.0 at least.

Comment: @MartyFouts Do you want to write that up as an answer? It works. Do you have any idea why it doesn't? (And for documentation purposes, I'm using 2.92.0 - haven't been able to use Blender in at least a year. I REALLY have to upgrade!)

Comment: The normals are inverted on your boolean object. If you reset them in Edit mode with SHFT-N it works fine even in Exact mode.

Comment: @Tango Perhaps you could ask John Eason to write up an answer that mentions both checking normals and trying the fast solver?  If he doesn't want to write an answer, then I will, with an explanation of how the normals matter.

Comment: @JohnEason - Did you see Marty's suggestion? So all I have to do is select that prism, go into edit mode and hit SHIFT-N?  - Okay, just tried that. Duplicated the object, dragged it into place, hit TAB to get to edit move, hit SHIFT-N, and went back to Object Mode. I didn't see any marking indicating it worked in Exact mode, so I changed to Fast mode and it worked there.

Comment: Yes I did, but since you'd uploaded your blend file I thought I'd have a look at it. The first thing I do with a problem file is turn on Face Orientation on the top-right Viewport Overlays menu and that showed up the inverted normals immediately. I flipped them and Exact mode worked straight away. I'll do a write-up at @MartyFouts suggestion when I'm fully awake! (I suspect this might have been causing the problem that you had with filling faces in your earlier question too.)

Comment: @JohnEason thanks for writing your answer. You definitely deserved the upvotes and accept, since I only took the easy way out

Comment: @MartyFouts No problem. I must admit that I was surprised to see the normals on the main object flip when using the Fast solver though! No idea what could cause that!

Comment: @JohnEason Still going through your answer - lots of distractions today. I'll comment on it or respond to it once I've made sure I understand and can do everything in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normals are inverted on the modifier object. Turn on the Face Orientation overlay as shown below.
[image]As @MartyFouts says, using the Fast Solver option in the Boolean modifier does work in this case but for some reason it also flips the normals on the main object as shown below:[image]
Select the modifier object. Go into <kbd>Edit</kbd> mode and select <kbd>A</kbd>ll. Then hit <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to correct the normals.
[image]
Back in Object mode, hide the modifier and you'll see that it's worked correctly in Exact mode.[image]
Hint: Enable the Bool tool addon and you can use shortcut keys to add modifiers and turn on Wireframe in its preferences. Makes life much easier!

Comment: You just went through a thorough and expanded version of what was in your comments. I can't figure out why, but it didn't seem to work yesterday and works today. Honestly, I think I have to put that down to user error! I made a dupe of the prism, so I wouldn't mess it up with any mistakes, and moved it into place, did what you said, then went back to Object Mode, picked the cylinder and added the modifier. As soon as I picked the prism as the modifier, I could see the outline of the cut in the cylinder in Exact mode. Thank you! Any idea why the normals were inverted?

Comment: It's quite easy to get normals inverted without realising to be honest. To demonstrate, add a plane to a new scene, turn on the Face Orientation overlay and in Edit mode, first extrude the plane up then undo with CTRL-Z and extrude it down!

Comment: Thanks for that and all the other info on this! There is still so much I'm learning just to create and manipulate objects - and I haven't even come close to trying to animate! This started as frustrating but I've learned something useful!

Answer (score 0):

I realize you didn't ask for it now, but I just felt like rebuilding the thing with *Geometry Nodes*.

...Maybe it will help you.

The practical thing is: **It is 100% procedural!**

So you can always edit the mesh non-destructively.

The only starting point is the curve you created (note the center of the curve).

[image]

Basically I do exactly what you have done step by step so far:

1. I duplicate the curve so that I get the desired shape.
2. I create a filled polygon from it
3. Then I extrude this shape
4. I also create some cylinders in different sizes
5. And finally I use the node `Mesh Boolean` to cut the parts.

[image]

Comment: I'm curious.  How much longer did it take you to create that node tree than the 20 or so seconds it took me to create the  geometry?

Comment: ....honestly I have no idea, but time is relative :D

Comment: It might be for some folks, but others have a life! :^)

Comment: Time may be relative, but when you're setting up something that will eventually be part of how you're paying for the rent, it's a big issue. Thank you for the work and information, but there's no way I can spare all that time every time I create a new shape I want to use for a new pottery extruder die.

Comment: @Tango & Mr. John: Come on, I find that really a little inappropriate and cheeky to criticize me here and let go of stupid innuendos here. I wasn't the one who had a problem with a task. I was the one who gave you an additional solution, which is not bad. And for free to boot. That's just ungrateful and pretty much missing the point! It is ultimately up to you which solution you prefer, but this platform is certainly not about your sensitivities, but about providing answers to questions so that others can also benefit from them.

Comment: I think you missed my smiley there! I wasn't criticising your efforts!

Comment: @JohnEason OK, I obviously misunderstood that. Telling someone that you have no life is just inappropriate. Even as a joke. Procedural saves time in the end, if you can hook in any curve and the result fits. Or not?

Comment: Fair enough. Sadly a lot of long-time Blender users are put off learning procedural nodes because they don't think they'll understand them.

Comment: Not trying to say at all that you have no life, but I think it's a fair point that this may work, but if you're doing this kind of thing for a job, where time is a limited resource, it's rather intensive.

Comment: @Tango No, that's the point: If someone else has already built a ready-made node setup for you, then all you have to do is draw your curve and the part is ready. That's the essence of procedural 3D design and *Geometry Nodes*. I'm afraid you haven't quite understood something here. But anyway, that's your decision ;-)